# Iterate and compare two objects simultaneously in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two objects `obj_a` and `obj_b`, and would to compare their keys. Keys in `obj_a` should appear in `obj_b`.

The code below loops through nested objects and works fine. How can I compare keys of `obj_b` inside the loop?

I cannot use another other method like `JSON.stringify(obj_a) === JSON.stringify(obj_b)` because if keys match I need to do other things in there.

```
var obj_a = {
    k1:"OBJ1 K1",
    k2: "OBJ1 K2",
    k3: {
        k3A: "OBJ1 K3"
    }
}

var obj_b = {
    k1:"OBJ2 K1",
    k2: "OBJ2 K2",
    k3: {
        k3A: "OBJ2 K3"
    }
}

hasKeys = function(a,b){
    iterateThrough = function(obj){
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(curKey){
            if(typeof obj[curKey]==='object'){
                console.log('Loop A '+curKey  )
                iterateThrough(obj[curKey]);
            } else {
                console.log('Loop B '+obj[curKey])
            } 
        });
    } 
    iterateThrough(a);
}

hasKeys(obj_a,obj_b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adds a second parameter and traverses b at the same time.

```js
var obj_a = {
    k1:"OBJ1 K1",
    k2: "OBJ1 K2",
    k3: {
        k3A: "OBJ1 K3"
    },
    k4: "OBJ1 K4"
}

var obj_b = {
    k1:"OBJ2 K1",
    k2: "OBJ2 K2",
    k3: {
        k3A: "OBJ2 K3"
    }
}

hasKeys = function(a,b){
    iterateThrough = function(obj,b){
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(curKey){
            // [curKey]: is object, traverse
            if(typeof obj[curKey]==='object' && typeof b[curKey]==='object'){
                console.log('Loop A '+curKey  )
                iterateThrough(obj[curKey],b[curKey]);
            } else {
                if(b.hasOwnProperty(curKey))
                  console.log('Loop B '+obj[curKey]+' b='+b[curKey]);
                else
                  console.log('b does not have this key: ' + curKey);
            } 
        });
    } 
    iterateThrough(a,b);
}

hasKeys(obj_a,obj_b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify` to convert it into string and then check if index of the key in both the string is same or not

```js
var obj_a = {
  k1: "OBJ1 K1",
  k2: "OBJ1 K2",
  k3: {
    k3A: "OBJ1 K3"
  }
}

var obj_b = {
  k1: "OBJ2 K1",
  k2: "OBJ2 K2",
  k3: {
    k3A: "OBJ2 K3"
  },
  k3A: "OBJ2 K3"
};



function checkKey(objA, ObjB, key) {
  key = key.toLowerCase();
  const strfyA = JSON.stringify(objA).toLowerCase();
  const strfyB = JSON.stringify(ObjB).toLowerCase();
  console.log(strfyB.indexOf(key), strfyA.indexOf(key));
  return strfyB.indexOf(key) === strfyA.indexOf(key)

}

console.log(checkKey(obj_a, obj_b, 'K3A'))
```